# Show using the fixed point theorem that if $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}[1-x-\frac{1}{10}x^5]$ is defined on $I=\{x|0 \leq x \leq 1\}$ then it has a zero in $I$

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

The main idea here is to apply the fixed point theorem to $g(x)=f(x)+x$, in order to show that f has a zero in $I$. If $g$ has a fixed point (i.e. $g(x_0)=x_0$), then $f(x_0)=0$. I just don't see how to show that $d(g(x),g(y))=d(f(x)+x,f(y)+y) \leq kd(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in I$, and with $0<k<1$, which is necessary to apply the fixed point theorem to $g$.

**EDIT:**

This is an exercise designed to help me learn how to use the following fixed point theorem:

If $f$ is a mapping on a complete metric space $S$ into $S$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \leq kd(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in S$ with $0<k<1$, then the mapping has a unique fixed point.

Comment: Isn't the intermediate value theorem sufficient? $f(0)=1/4>0$ and $f(1)=-1/40<0$.

Comment: $f(0)=\frac14$ and $f(1)=-\frac{1}{40}$.  $f$ is continuous and so, there must be a root on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @DanielEscudero I edited the title. This is a problem to help me learn about the fixed point theorem.

Comment: The next part of the problem is to find the zero using an iteration process

Comment: Which fixed point theorem? There are an awful lot of them.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, I didn't realize that. I've clarified with an edit.

Comment: Where is $k$ used in your definition? Did you mean $d(f(x),f(y))\leq kd(x,y)$? @ztforster

Comment: More apologies. It's fixed

Comment: Let me know if my answer suffices. I just want to give you the best answer I can give you!

Comment: Note, you also need that $0\leq g(x)\leq 1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV You need to prove that the function $g$ goes from $[0,1]$ into $[0,1]$. That makes part of the hypothesis of the theorem ztforster is using (Bannach fixed point theorem).

Comment: @DanielEscudero Thanks! Yes, you are correct.  I was wondering as to the context of the statement.  But "at"ThomasAndrews is always spot on in his answers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I understand the context of the statement.  As always, your comments are spot on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the MVT, $g(x)-g(y) =g'(\xi) (x-y)$ for $0<\xi<1$. Thus,

$$\begin{align}
|g(x)-g(y)| & =|g'(\xi)| |(x-y)| \\
& = \left(\frac34 -\frac18 \xi^4\right) |x-y| \\
& \le \frac34 |x-y| \\
& < (1) |x-y|
\end{align}$$

Comment: This works just fine for me, you were just beaten for time :)

Comment: My pleasure.  I got a tighter bound for you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}|g(x)-g(y)|&=\left|\frac{3}{4}(x-y)-\frac{1}{40}(x^5-y^5)\right|\\
&\leq\frac{3}{4}\left|x-y\right|+\frac{1}{40}\left|x^5-y^5\right|\\
&=\frac{3}{4}\left|x-y\right|+\frac{1}{40}\left|x-y\right|(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)\\
&\leq\frac{3}{4}\left|x-y\right|+\frac{5}{40}\left|x-y\right|\\
&=\frac{35}{40}\left|x-y\right|\end{align}$$

You can take $k=35/40 = 7/8<1$.

Comment: Really valuable to learn the latex `\begin{align}...\end{align}` for this sort of expression.

Comment: Do you mean that way? Mmm I don't see it better... Should a \displaystyle fix it?

Comment: I've just done it for you. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Of course I don't! I was trying it, but you were faster. Thanks a lot for the advice! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You need one more fact for this to be complete - you need $0\leq g(x)\leq 1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Comment: Good solution!  I always like the brute force approach.

Comment: It works for me :) We still need to verify Thomas' comment.